# Sorting Parse results by objectId of pointer

Tags: javascript, pointers, parse-platform

I'm using Javascript and I have two Parse tables. One table has a "user" field with that has a pointer to the user table. I want to do a query on the first table where I filter the results by the objectId of the pointer ("user" field).

I've tried several things such as using dot notation and containerIn and equalTo or matches query with an inner query.  From looking at other sources I get the feeling it's up one of these two allys but clearly I'm not executing well.  Here is the code from one of my attempts:

```
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
innerQuery.equalTo("objectId", conId); //where conId is an array of ObjectIds
tQuery.matchesQuery("user", innerQuery); //where "user" is the field in the tQuery table with the pointer to the User table.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can qualify the pointer field directly by using use objects -- not just ids -- when stating the test...

```
var someUser = Parse.User.createWithoutData("objectId");  // replace objectId with an actual "xyz123" id
var tQuery = new Parse.Query // ...
tQuery.equalTo("user", someUser);
```

Comment: var someUser = Parse.User.createWithoutData("objectId"); produces the following error:  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: No matter what I try I just get bad request. This seems really simple but I'm drowning here!